# Powershell - Add-OdbcDsn - Does not set properties for driver even if valid

Tags: powershell, db2, odbc

I want to use Powershell to create a Db2 System DSN. This code does create the data source

```
Add-OdbcDsn -Name "FromPowershell" -DriverName "IBM DB2 ODBC DRIVER - DB2COPY1"  -DsnType "System" -Platform "32-bit" -SetPropertyValue @("DateTimeStringFormat=EUR","DbAlias=SYST")
```

But, only the DbAlias is set as property, not the DatetimeStringFormat. It is valid for the Db2 driver as seen below.

I did also believe that if I could create it manually and then use Powershell to extract the parameters afterwards I could solve it by "reverse engineering", but no - I have not been able to find how to use get-odbcdsn to show all parameters either.

[image]

### Version info

Windows

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      14393  0
```

Powershell

```
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      1      14393  3383
```

Db2
IBM Db2 Server Data Client 11.5

```
Product name:                     "DB2 Connect Unlimited Edition for zSeries"
Version information:              "11.5"
```

### Where properties are kept

While deleting the datasource you will be prompted with "Will you delete properties as well in db2cli.ini and db2dsdriver.cfg

```
C:\ProgramData\IBM\DB2\DB2COPY1\cfg\db2cli.ini
```

there I found

```
[FromPowershell]
DBALIAS=SYST
DateTimeStringFormat=EUR
```

which does not answer my question, but at least I did learn that it is not stored in registry.

Comment: Does the behavior change if you re-order the property strings? ie. `-SetPropertyValue @("DbAlias=SYST","DateTimeStringFormat=EUR")`

Comment: Edit your question to show the Powershell version, the windows-version, and the output of the db2level command (if using an IBM driver).

Comment: Updated with version

An no, changing the order did not help